# Generic java factory for generic interface types

Tags: java, generics

I don't use Generics a lot but I get the feeling what I want here is not actually possible.  Let's say I have a parameterized interface like:

```
public interface baseType<M, V> {}
```

I have two classes that implement this interface with concrete type params

```
public class ConcreteA implements baseType<MyType1, MyType2> {}

public class ConcreteB implements baseType<MyType3, MyType4> {}
```

now let's say I want to make a Factory to use in the client code that decides between which concrete class to implement based on type:

```
public class MyFactory {
    public static baseType<?, ?> getConcreteObjectForType(MyType type){
        switch(type){
            case TYPE_A:
                return new ConcreteA();
            case TYPE_B:
                return new ConcreteB();
        }

    public Enum MyType { TYPE_A, TYPE_B }
}
```

In the client code I would like to do

```
baseType concrete = MyFactory.getConcreteObjectForType(MyType.TYPE_A);
```

Is something like this possible?  If I can't make a factory in this way, what is the proper creational pattern for such a scenario?

Comment: In the client code, how would you parametrize `baseType concrete = ...`? If `MyType1` and `MyType3` have a greatest a common ancestor `M1` and `MyType2` and `MyType4` have a greatest a common ancestor `M2` you could do something like `baseType<? extends M1, ? extends M2>` (or `super` instead of `extends` if you have contra variance instead of covariance).

Comment: Not really, no.  The "proper creational pattern" is not to try to extract common code, but to do `switch(type) { case TYPE_A : ConcreteA foo = new ConcreteA(); // do everything ConcreteA-specific ...}` instead of trying to factor out a common `concrete` object.

Comment: @Alec yes, unfortunatly they do not have common ancestors.  I suppose I am SOL :*(

Comment: If either of you would like to give a more detailed answer about why this doesn't work - I would accept it.